# Ola Hallengren Scripts and Maintenance Plan Editor - How to execute sequentially on completion?

Tags: scripting, maintenance, ola-hallengren

I'm using Ola Hallengren's scripts to perform maintenance on my databases. In the Maintenance Plan Designer I am trying to setup a plan that works step by step, but no matter what I try everything gets executed at one time.

My first and second attempts, left column in the photo, was to use "execute job" and call each job in the order I want.  The first constraint was "success" but all jobs execute at once.  So I tried "completion" next.  Same result.  I then constructed the same tree using execute t-sql instead of execute job using this code:

```
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name ='DatabaseIntegrityCheck - USER_DATABASES';
GO
```

One again I got the same result, everything executes at the same time.  I even tried adding a @return_value for executing sp_start_job but that did nothing either.  Finally I tried one script like this:

```
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name ='DatabaseIntegrityCheck - USER_DATABASES';
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name ='DatabaseIntegrityCheck - SYSTEM_DATABASES';
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name ='IndexOptimize - USER_DATABASES';
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name ='DatabaseBackup - USER_DATABASES - FULL';
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name ='DatabaseBackup - SYSTEM_DATABASES - FULL';
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name ='DatabaseBackup - USER_DATABASES - LOG';
GO
```

And it also executes everything at once.  Besides scheduling them one by one in the maintenance plan editor at different times, is there any way I can make them execute one after another.  I'm not concerned if they succeed or not, I just want one to run then the next instead of everything at once.

[image: Maintenance Plan Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just run each job as a seperate step?

[image]

And so on and so forth

Comment: I'll give this a try tonight and see how it works.  Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be the key, I guess when you set it up under the Maintenance Plan screen it only counts it as a success/completion when the code executes, not that the job completes.  This worked much better.